# How to find closest AWS region (when service not available in one region)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am in Singapore (ap-southeast-1) but want to use Cognito. So how do I identify which is the best region to use for the service?

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region) lists the region where Cognito is available. You can use [AWS Global Infrasturcture](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/) to determine the nearest region where Cognito is available.

Nearest Cognito availability is in:

- `ap-south-1` (Asia-Pacific Mumbai)
- `ap-northeast-2` (Asia-Pacific Seoul)
- `ap-northeast-1` (Asia-Pacific Tokyo)

Or use a third party tool like [CloudPing](http://www.cloudping.info/) to find the region nearest to you based on latency.

Answer (score 0):

When using AWS Cognito, selecting the nearest region is not a must since the interaction with Cognito in your main application flow is not frequent. Cognito mainly involves in the login flow, where you can generally accept the delay of few hundreds of milliseconds at most.

Anyways, since reducing latency is better, you you can select the following regions(Recommended in order) based on the [AWS Inter-Region Latency](https://www.cloudping.co/) results.

1. `ap-south-1` (Asia-Pacific Mumbai)
2. `ap-northeast-1` (Asia-Pacific Tokyo)